# Unity injection on runtime

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I am using `Unity` to inject parameter into class when ASP.net Web API started, for example I am injecting Sendgrid API key into mail class:

```
container.RegisterType<IMail, Mail>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), 
                new InjectionConstructor(new InjectionParameter<string>("SG.XXXX.....")));
```

But for multi tenant environment, I would like to have different API key for different tenant, which is store in the database.

> How can I have the API Key injected during run-time?

Comment: read it from somewhere .. (file? .. db?)

Comment: Not yet implement, but from mongodb or redis db.